# Issue with linq filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two tables (one is assignments and the other is participants). I am using the following code

```
public ActionResult Index(string subjectId) // filter participants based on the subject that they belong to 
{

    var participants = db.Participant.Where(x => x.SubjectsID.ToString().Contains(subjectId)).ToList();

    return View(participants);
}
```

The following code just returns a blank list

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: First explain properly what is your real issue instead down vote to all answer.

Comment: I think both " SubjectsID " and " subjectId " are same type , so you dont need to SubjectsID.ToString(). Just do the following " x.SubjectsID == subjectId "

Comment: @JasmineScott What is the type of Participant.SubjectsID?

Comment: @BasantaMatia Maybe you shouldn't answer when the question isn't clear.

Comment: It's not clear from your code (+ comments) what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: Its a string...

Comment: @JasmineScott Could you please provide more specs about your models definitions?

Comment: Show your complete list of participants and your `subjectId`.

Answer (score 1):

```
        {            
            var participants = db.Participant.Where(x => x.SubjectsID.ToLower().Contains(subjectId.ToLower())).ToList();            
            return View(participants);
        }
```

this will give all the records exists with the required subjects

Comment: If there´s no entry that *contains* the `subjectId`, how should there be any that *equals* it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere can you please provide a linq for this

Comment: @Jasmine Scott please debug your program and check if your DB contains any records with the subjectID what you are looking for

Comment: I have checked this and there is entry in the database

Comment: Quite simple, let´s assume we´re looking for `subjectId = "MyID"`. With contains we could now search for `participants.Where(x => x.Contains("MyId")`, but how should `Where(x => x == "MyID")` or `Where(x => x.Equals("MyID"))` return something different? There is no element containing `"MyID".

Comment: @HimBrolBeere here we are searching for exact match not a string which contains the characters we are looking for, so still do you think we need to go for contains instead of Where, if so then what will be difference between them

Comment: I think we should know the type of Participant.SubjectsID first

Comment: Participant.SubjectID is a string

Comment: @JasmineScott and what exactly does the Participant.SubjectsID string contain?

Comment: Have you debug your program is their any record exists with the subject ID what you are looking for, has your parameter is going to be same with the DB

Comment: The thing is, if there´s not even a string that more or less is *similar* to our search-string (which `Contains` will check), than there *can´t be* any that *exactly equals* our search-string. Thus if `Contains` does not find anything, `Equals` (or `==`) will neither.

Comment: yes sorry i didn't saw the type just now found that the type is string, i have updated my answer and it is possible that she is not getting the result because of Case sensitive, i have casted it to lower before checking she should get the result what is expected

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
var participants = db.Participant.Where(x => x.SubjectsID == subjectId).ToList();
```

instead of

```
var participants = db.Participant.Where(x => x.SubjectsID.ToString().Contains(subjectId)).ToList();
```

Comment: If there´s no entry that *contains* the `subjectId`, how should there be any that *equals* it?

Comment: @JasmineScott What is the type of Participant.SubjectsID?

Answer (score 0):

Just check with equal to operator,

```
public ActionResult Index(string subjectId)
 {
  var participants = db.Participant.Where(x =>
                     x.SubjectsID.ToString() == subjectId).ToList();
  return View(participants);
 }
```

Hope it helps :)